# Mexico is a feast for the eyes, correct grammar?

Tags: gramática

I am trying to say

> Mexico is a feast for the eyes.

Would this be grammatically correct?

> **Mexico es una festín para los ojos.**

Answer (score 3):

[`Festín` is masculine](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=fest%C3%ADn), so you need an article that agrees with that gender (`un` and not `una`).

> México es **un** festín para los ojos.

Also, don't forget that in Spanish "Mexico" is an *esdrújula* word, and as such it needs the accented `é` (which I know that is one of those really tricky characters on certain keyboards, but is best to get used to use a proper spelling. Pays off in the long run).

Thus said, although that sentence is technically correct (and translates that part of "for the eyes" of your original sentence) I would favor the use of "la vista" ("the sight",  instead). Also (and this is completely me), I have a much stronger association of `festín` with the second meaning provided in the link (*Banquete espléndido*/Banquet) than with the first one (*Festejo*/Festival), so I would have favored the use of the word `Fiesta` instead of "Festín" (again, this might be just a personal preference due to regional differences in Spanish).

> México es una fiesta para la vista.
>
> México es una fiesta para los ojos.

"Fiesta" es feminine, so I used "una".

Instead of "fiesta" or "festín" you could also use `Regalo`. Is is quite common when referring to senses.

> Ese paisaje tan bello es un regalo para la vista
>
> Esa fruta tan jugosa es un regalo para el paladar (o para *el gusto*)
>
> Esa experiencia es un regalo para los sentidos

Comment: Acabo de ver que te has dado de alto en el *Club de 4000*.  ¡Enhorabuena!

Comment: @guifa, gracias! A ver si encuentro cómo canjear los puntos por una _mountain bike_ o un jamón... ;-P

Comment: @Diego in my dialect of English feast here clearly means festin not fiesta. The image is of Mexico spread out for you to enjoy. We do also use the idiom 'feast your eyes on'. However that is just the literal translation and I am not sure about the Spanish idiom, regalo looks good to me.